# FFMPEG combining image, mp3, and logo watermark

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I thought this would work but I'm getting errors.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "ARTWORK.jpg" -filter_complex "overlay=80:0" -i "MUSIC.mp3" -i "WATERMARK.gif" -filter_complex "overlay=10:350" -s 640x480 -shortest -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart "CONVERTED.mp4"
```

If I do not put the -filter_complex "overlay=80:0"  part (to place the artwork "in the middle") it works, but the artwork does not center (it is a 480x480 jpeg)

The error i am getting is

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_overlay_0
```

It has something to do with there being 2 filter complex parts but both are necessary so not sure how to "label" them?

Comment: Of course you need to show the **complete** console output and not just a single line from it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard and the complete console output should always start with "I, the undersigned hereby certify and declare on my honour that I read the docs beforehand" :)

Comment: Found this page via google, with search term `ffmpeg Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad`. The issue for me was that I forgot the `-i` flag. One of those dumb errors that you continually overlook because "hey, I'm not *that* inept".

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: what the OP wanted to achieve was to be able to position two overlays. The obvious answer in this case is you to use a third input as the main input, for example a black frame:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:800x600 -i <image1> -i <image2> -i <audio> -filter_complex 'overlay=...,overlay=' <output>
```

---

An `overlay` filters needs **two inputs**: the main input and the superimposed input.

You have only 2 image inputs and so you cannot use two `overlay` filters in the same command since it would require a third visual stream. That's why is says it cannot find a matching stream.

For example you can use two overlay filters to add two different logos to a video:

```
ffmpeg -i input -i logo1 -i logo2 -filter_complex 'overlay=...,overlay=' output
```

In your case the main input is the artwork and watermark is the overlay which needs to be positioned in a single `overlay`.

Take a look at [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) because there are some parameters that might help you achieve your goal no matter the input size. See the main and overlay input width and height: `main_w`, `main_h`, `overlay_w`, `overlay_h`.

Example usage (overlay at 10px from lower-right bottom corner):

`overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10`

Comment: this doesnt answer any of my issues... like i said it works fine if i dont try to position the 2nd overlay (watermark).  adding both overlays separated by a comma in filter_complex gives me the same error as before.  so how would i position both the JPG and the GIF to x,y coordinates without the label error?

Comment: @b747fp Yes it does, read my answer again. You cannot use two overlays because you only have two inputs (the audio doesn't count because you can't overlay an image on the audio stream). You can either overlay the jpg on the gif or the gif on the jpg with a **single** overlay.

Comment: The comma separated overlay was an example for a **video input** where you overlay 2 images on 1 video stream = 3 inputs. You only have 2.

Comment: This command works but i need ARTWORK to be placed 80 pixels from the left.

    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "ARTWORK.jpg" -i "MUSIC.mp3" -i "WATERMARK.gif" -filter_complex "overlay=80:00" -s 640x480 -shortest -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart "CONVERTED.mp4"

Comment: The ARTWORK is the main input, not the overlay. The `overlay` controls the position of the second image, in your case the WATERMARK. Put the WATERMARK first in your command if you want the `overlay` to affect the ARTWORK position. Is it clear, because I can also draw nice diagrams :) ?

Comment: but i need to do x,y positioning on BOTH the artwork and the watermark. ive tried rearranging the inputs and overlays they all result in the same error when i try to set positioning on both.... so i dont think a diagram will help.

Comment: Then you could use a blank image (black?) as main input (first `-i`) + your 2 images + 1 audio. In this case you'll have 3 v:inputs and you can position both the artwork and the watermark using 2 x `overlay`.

Comment: nope now it just keeps saying "Option loop not found."  when i add a 3rd image input

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "BACKGROUND.gif" -i "MUSIC.mp3" -i "ARTWORK.jpg" -i "WATERMARK.gif" -filter_complex "overlay=x=80:y=0,overlay=x=10:y=350" -s 640x480 -shortest -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -movflags faststart "CONVERTED.mp4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90133/discussion-between-b747fp-and-aergistal).